# Circular argument reference with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to run the command `rails g devise:install` in my rails project, but it's not working. here's some more info.

```
/Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
/Users/Sam/Documents/workspace/cc1/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for #<Cc1::Application:0x007fb2b25cee98> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Sam/Documents/workspace/cc1/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
    from /Users/Sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

Some more information:

```
Ruby Version: 2.2.2

Rails Version: 4.0.0

Gemfile:

source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.2"

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem "paperclip-dropbox", ">= 1.1.7"
gem "figaro"
gem 'devise'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

I'm guessing that this isn't a devise issue. Please let me know what's going on. I have tried running bundle install and bundle update, and these pass through just fine.

Comment: Most times this is because you're passing an argument that could also be a method of in the class. But this seems to be occuring inside your environment.rb, so could you paste both your `config/environment.rb` and `config/environments/development.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with [ActiveSupport prior to Rails 4.1.9](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8fd52705eda6a2cd7e9a8a5bc723fa094e359eb7). Upgrade your [Rails version](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8fd52705eda6a2cd7e9a8a5bc723fa094e359eb7) and you should be in good shape.

Comment: Nice catch! Curious to learn how you knew about this? I knew it had to be about passing a method as a parameter name, but didn't know it started with Ruby 2.2.

Comment: @oreo Some time ago I tried building a Rails 4.1 app with Devise that didn't have the fix. I googled and wound up on a page for a different gem that shared the same problem.